# msysgit multi command alias

Tags: git, msysgit

I'm trying to put a multi command git alias in my .gitconfig per: [YUI Gallery Doc](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/developer)

I'm using git from the msysgit bash shell. Neither of the commands from the doc work for me:

```
[aliases]
    pu = !"git fetch origin -vn git fetch upstream -vn git merge upstream/master"
```

gives:

```
$ git pu
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mjhm/.ssh/id_rsa':
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref git
```

However

```
[alias]
    pu = !"git fetch origin -v; git fetch upstream -v; git merge upstream/master"
```

gives:

```
$ git pu
error: unknown switch `;'
usage: git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
...
```

How do I get a multi command alias to work in msysgit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yahoo UI documentation seems to use a way of chaining git commands that is different from the one that is [documented by git](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Poor_man.27s_.22stash.22).

By applying that logic, I would use the following line:

```
pu = ! git fetch origin -v && git fetch upstream -v && git merge upstream/master
```

(I believe that in the windows version, the "n" should have been a "\n". But that does not work from msysgit bash - maybe that would work from cmd.com)

Comment: perfect, except the end should be upstream/master